# Why does my fe with demeaned data ( lm() ) not reproduce coefficients from plm(), lfe() and lsdv?

Tags: r, lm, panel-data, plm, lfe

I am trying to reproduce fixed effects coefficients for panel data using different packages and techniques: (1) `plm()`, (2) `lfe()`, (3) dummy-lsdv with `lm()`, and (4) demeaned-fe with `lm()`.

My data set consists of 1581 observations and 13 variables. It is survey data from 527 respondents (var = respondent) in 3 waves (var = wave). I have one DV (y) and 10 IVs (x1 to x10).

The data set looks like this:

```
  respondent  wave      y    x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6    x7    x8    x9   x10
       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1          1     1  1         1     2    NA    NA     2   1     1.5  NA      NA     2
2          1     2 NA         2    NA     0     0     0   1     4     4       1     3
3          1     3 NA         4     5    NA    NA    NA  NA     8    NA      NA     1
4          2     1  0.931     3     3     2     2     2   4     7.5   7.5    NA     3
5          2     2  0.986     4    NA    NA     2     2   4.5   6.5   5       3     4
6          2     3  0.986     4     3     2     2     2   3     3     3       2     3
```

**My question:**  When I perform fixed effects regressions with (1) `plm()`, (2) `lfe()`, and (3) dummy-lsdv with `lm()`, the models always return the same coefficients. However, when I perform a fixed effects regression using (4) demeaned data and the `lm()` package, I get different coefficients. This puzzles me and I wonder: **why?**

Here is my code:

**1. `plm()`:**

Input:

```
library(plm)
model_plm <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10,
             data = dataset,
             index=c("respondent","wave"),
             model = "within",
             effect = 'individual')
summary(model_plm)
```

Output:

```
Unbalanced Panel: n = 228, T = 1-2, N = 316

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.3240866 -0.0048416  0.0000000  0.0048416  0.3240866 

Coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
x1  -0.0216484  0.0167614 -1.2916  0.20032  
x2   0.0178114  0.0141219  1.2613  0.21097  
x3  -0.0145262  0.0103954 -1.3974  0.16627  
x4  -0.0061660  0.0133069 -0.4634  0.64439  
x5   0.0174401  0.0144256  1.2090  0.23032  
x6  -0.0053556  0.0067210 -0.7968  0.42796  
x7   0.0065517  0.0097627  0.6711  0.50415  
x8  -0.0151375  0.0081992 -1.8462  0.06865 .
x9   0.0235351  0.0092612  2.5412  0.01303 *
x10  0.0235181  0.0228927  1.0273  0.30745  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**2. `lfe()`:**

Input:

```
library(lfe)
model_lfe <- felm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 | respondent, data = dataset)
summary(model_lfe)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
x1  -0.021648   0.016761  -1.292   0.2003  
x2   0.017811   0.014122   1.261   0.2110  
x3  -0.014526   0.010395  -1.397   0.1663  
x4  -0.006166   0.013307  -0.463   0.6444  
x5   0.017440   0.014426   1.209   0.2303  
x6  -0.005356   0.006721  -0.797   0.4280  
x7   0.006552   0.009763   0.671   0.5041  
x8  -0.015138   0.008199  -1.846   0.0687 .
x9   0.023535   0.009261   2.541   0.0130 *
x10  0.023518   0.022893   1.027   0.3074  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**3. LSDV with `lm()`:**

Input:

```
model_lsdv <- lm(y ~ as_factor(respondent) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10, data = dataset)
options(max.print=2000)
summary(model_lsdv)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            0.9499746  0.1505806   6.309 1.57e-08 ***
[...]    
x1                    -0.0216484  0.0167614  -1.292  0.20032    
x2                     0.0178114  0.0141219   1.261  0.21097    
x3                    -0.0145262  0.0103954  -1.397  0.16627    
x4                    -0.0061660  0.0133069  -0.463  0.64439    
x5                     0.0174401  0.0144256   1.209  0.23032    
x6                    -0.0053556  0.0067210  -0.797  0.42796    
x7                     0.0065517  0.0097627   0.671  0.50415    
x8                    -0.0151375  0.0081992  -1.846  0.06865 .  
x9                     0.0235351  0.0092612   2.541  0.01303 *  
x10                    0.0235181  0.0228927   1.027  0.30745    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**4. Demeaned FE with `lm()`:**

Input:

```
dataset_demeaned <- with(dataset, data.frame(respondent = respondent,
                                             wave = wave,
                                             y = y - ave(y, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x1 = x1 - ave(x1, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x2 = x2 - ave(x2, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x3 = x3 - ave(x3, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x4 = x4 - ave(x4, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x5 = x5 - ave(x5, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x6 = x6 - ave(x6, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x7 = x7 - ave(x7, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x8 = x8 - ave(x8, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x9 = x9 - ave(x9, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x10 = x10 - ave(x10, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T))
                                            )
                        )

model_dmd <- lm(y ~ 0 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10, data = dataset_demeaned)
summary(model_dmd)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
x1  -0.006223   0.008220  -0.757  0.44957   
x2   0.013181   0.007880   1.673  0.09543 . 
x3  -0.012807   0.005484  -2.335  0.02018 * 
x4  -0.006431   0.006311  -1.019  0.30900   
x5   0.015455   0.005941   2.602  0.00973 **
x6  -0.001429   0.003402  -0.420  0.67483   
x7   0.004362   0.004698   0.929  0.35387   
x8  -0.009336   0.004366  -2.139  0.03326 * 
x9   0.015731   0.005267   2.987  0.00305 **
x10  0.007631   0.010922   0.699  0.48529   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**More information:**
I have already performed these checks:

- I have used other ways to demean the data, e.g. the `demean()` function. --> Same results as in 4.
- I have calculated some of the demeaned data by hand, which produces the same results as the `ave()` and the `demean()` functions.
- I have played around with the `na.action` option because I hoped that the problem might result from a different treatment of missing values. But it did not change the results.
- I've once included the respondent variable `as_factor` in the (4) demeaned fe model. Like: `model_dmd <- lm(y ~ 0 + as_factor(respondent) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10, data = dataset_demeaned)`. This approach reproduced the correct coefficients. However, demeaning should already take care of unobserved heterogeneity and thus the inclusion of dummies seems redundant.

So my best guess is that the problem does not come from the process of demeaning, but from the `lm()` function. Maybe the fact that the panel is `unbalanced` plays a role here?

I am very thankful for any suggestions and explanations!

---

**SOLUTION**:

Thanks to @G.Grothendieck, I can post the solution here. The correct code of (4) Demeaned FE with `lm()` should read as:

Input:

```
# Delete all rows with NAs
dataset <- na.omit(dataset)

# Demean the rows that are left behind
dataset_demeaned <- with(dataset, data.frame(respondent = respondent,
                                             wave = wave,
                                             y = y - ave(y, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x1 = x1 - ave(x1, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x2 = x2 - ave(x2, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x3 = x3 - ave(x3, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x4 = x4 - ave(x4, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x5 = x5 - ave(x5, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x6 = x6 - ave(x6, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x7 = x7 - ave(x7, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x8 = x8 - ave(x8, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x9 = x9 - ave(x9, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)),
                                             x10 = x10 - ave(x10, respondent, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T))
                                             )
                         )

model_dmd <- lm(y ~ 0 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10, data = dataset_demeaned)
summary(model_dmd)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x1  -0.021648   0.008462  -2.558 0.011004 *  
x2   0.017811   0.007130   2.498 0.013009 *  
x3  -0.014526   0.005248  -2.768 0.005989 ** 
x4  -0.006166   0.006718  -0.918 0.359452    
x5   0.017440   0.007283   2.395 0.017240 *  
x6  -0.005356   0.003393  -1.578 0.115530    
x7   0.006552   0.004929   1.329 0.184768    
x8  -0.015138   0.004140  -3.657 0.000301 ***
x9   0.023535   0.004676   5.033 8.24e-07 ***
x10  0.023518   0.011558   2.035 0.042734 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @G.Grothendieck! So it is the NAs! To clarify for readers: You need to put the command `dataset <- na.omit(dataset)` **before** starting the process of demeaning. This will delete all rows that contain NAs. Afterwards the coefficients will be reproduced correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By demeaning each column separately this is handling the NAs inconsistently. Each row has to be used or not used. One can't use a row for one variable and not for another.